# Which op amp circuit is this?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm new to op-amps and trying to find whether this is a common op-amp circuit. I've looked through this [op-amp circuit collection](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf) but I couldn't find it.

[image]

Is this a well-known / commonly used op-amp circuit? If so, which one is it?

Comment: It's an inverting amplifier with low-pass filters at the input and outputs. But we wouldn't call this an "op-amp", we'd call it an "op-amp circuit". The op-amp is just the single amplifier component represented by the triangle in the middle of the drawing. It could be any of thousands of available part numbers.

Comment: Take a look in this link under inverting amplifier. http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/ece3050/sp04/OpAmps01.pdf   I believe what you are confused on is the resitor on the output. It is a load resistor and is used to meet output resistance among other things. The rest is there to act as RC filtering, etc. Not a lot of time, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an inverting amplifier, with a no-load gain of \$-\dfrac{R_b}{R_1+R_a}\$ at DC.

There are low-pass filters on the input and output, with cutoff frequencies of \$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi  RC}\$ where \$R = R_1||R_a\$ for the input circuit and \$R_2\$ for the output circuit.

Comment: It's an operational amplifier connected as an inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit consists of 3 discrete circuits:

1. \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$ are a low pass filter with \$f3db = \dfrac{1}{2\pi R_1 C_1}\$
2. \$R_a\$, \$R_b\$ and op-amp are an inverting amplifier with the gain of \$-\dfrac{R_b}{R_a}\$
3. \$R_2\$ and \$C_2\$ are another low pass filter with \$f3db = \dfrac{1}{2\pi R2 C2}\$

Comment: Your first and second equations are not correct. They may be **approximately** correct if R1 << Ra, but you should state that.

Comment: if you write equations in imaginary terms (not as you declared just DC), my equations are more accurate @SpehroPefhany

Comment: R1 affects the gain, and Ra affects the f3db. The filter and the amplifier interact. If you had a voltage follower after the filter your equations would be correct.